# translate text with markup using polyglot.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

Using [polyglot.js](https://github.com/airbnb/polyglot.js), I wonder how to translate markup / components within texts? Consider the following text example:

```
with the <strong>free</strong> features you can <Link to="/pricing">achieve</Link> the following things
```

I could break that sentence down into multiple keys, but that wouldn't make sense when translating. What is a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agree with splitting it up is a bad idea...makes translation a bigger pain than needed.

looking at your tags your using react and node.js -> for react you could take the translated content from polyglot and use dangerouslysetinnerhtml https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

that's what would work - but honestly i would have a look at i18next (spoiler i'm the maintainer of that framework). With the react-i18next you can do those markup translations a lot nicer: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/

Using the trans component:

```
<Trans i18nKey="userMessagesUnread" count={count}>
  Hello <strong title={t('nameTitle')}>{{name}}</strong>, you have {{count}} unread message. <Link to="/msgs">Go to messages</Link>.
</Trans>
```

Comment: http://i18next.com -> runs on node.js too -> comes with middlewares for express, koa https://www.i18next.com/supported-frameworks.html

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is the argument for i18next over polyglot then